# Xcode crashes when I set a breakpoint in a completion callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, breakpoints, crash-reports

I get **Xcode quit unexpectedly while using the SimplePlayer plug-in.**
simpleplayer is the name of the app.

Xcode 6.2 only happens in simulator. IOS target 8.1 and above. App works normal without breakpoint.

This only happens when I set the breakpoint in the completion callback.

```
Time Awake Since Boot: 530 seconds

Crashed Thread:        21  <lldb.process.internal-state(pid=1263)>

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000032, 0x000000014057b3bc

kernel messages:
-1 sec              CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x14057b000): p=1151[Xcode] final status 0x3004200, denying page sending SIGKILL
-1 sec              CODE SIGNING: process 1151[Xcode]: rejecting invalid page at address 0x14057b000 from offset 0x225000 in file "/Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C7E8D457-BFAB-43DA-8B0C-D9010BBB1D88/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/77AB1811-69B6-4079-B874-8E20A7160283/SimplePlayer.app/SimplePlayer" (cs_mtime:1427477037.0 == mtime:1427477037.0) (signed:1 validated:1 tainted:1 wpmapped:0 slid:0)
Thread 21 Crashed:: <lldb.process.internal-state(pid=1263)>
0   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f2961f4 lldb_private::DataExtractor::GetU32_unchecked(unsigned long long*) const + 14
1   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f39af99 ObjectFileMachO::ParseSymtab() + 3603
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f39a0f2 ObjectFileMachO::GetSymtab() + 158
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f43f238 lldb_private::SymbolVendor::GetSymtab() + 64
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f2da04f lldb_private::Module::ResolveSymbolContextForAddress(lldb_private::Address const&, unsigned int, lldb_private::SymbolContext&, bool) + 333
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f287295 lldb_private::Address::CalculateSymbolContext(lldb_private::SymbolContext*, unsigned int) const + 157
6   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f42dede lldb_private::CompileUnit::ResolveSymbolContext(lldb_private::FileSpec const&, unsigned int, bool, bool, unsigned int, lldb_private::SymbolContextList&) + 630
7   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f23b32b lldb_private::BreakpointResolverFileLine::SearchCallback(lldb_private::SearchFilter&, lldb_private::SymbolContext&, lldb_private::Address*, bool) + 217
8   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f2efc8b lldb_private::SearchFilter::DoModuleIteration(lldb_private::SymbolContext const&, lldb_private::Searcher&) + 129
9   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f2f00dc lldb_private::SearchFilter::DoModuleIteration(std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Module> const&, lldb_private::Searcher&) + 86
10  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f2effc7 lldb_private::SearchFilter::SearchInModuleList(lldb_private::Searcher&, lldb_private::ModuleList&) + 241
11  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f23339e lldb_private::Breakpoint::ModulesChanged(lldb_private::ModuleList&, bool, bool) + 772
12  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f235955 lldb_private::BreakpointList::UpdateBreakpoints(lldb_private::ModuleList&, bool, bool) + 77
13  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f4798ab lldb_private::Target::ModulesDidLoad(lldb_private::ModuleList&) + 69
14  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f4797d6 lldb_private::Target::ModuleAdded(lldb_private::ModuleList const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Module> const&) + 444
15  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f2ddfad lldb_private::ModuleList::AppendImpl(std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Module> const&, bool) + 135
16  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f47909c lldb_private::Target::GetSharedModule(lldb_private::ModuleSpec const&, lldb_private::Error*) + 1576
17  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f3883b3 DynamicLoaderMacOSXDYLD::FindTargetModuleForDYLDImageInfo(DynamicLoaderMacOSXDYLD::DYLDImageInfo&, bool, bool*) + 331
18  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f38a28c DynamicLoaderMacOSXDYLD::UpdateImageInfosHeaderAndLoadCommands(std::__1::vector<DynamicLoaderMacOSXDYLD::DYLDImageInfo, std::__1::allocator<DynamicLoaderMacOSXDYLD::DYLDImageInfo> >&, unsigned int, bool) + 256
19  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f3898e5 DynamicLoaderMacOSXDYLD::AddModulesUsingImageInfosAddress(unsigned long long, unsigned int) + 153
20  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f389744 DynamicLoaderMacOSXDYLD::NotifyBreakpointHit(void*, lldb_private::StoppointCallbackContext*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 528
21  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f23a146 lldb_private::BreakpointOptions::InvokeCallback(lldb_private::StoppointCallbackContext*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 48
22  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f237462 lldb_private::BreakpointLocation::InvokeCallback(lldb_private::StoppointCallbackContext*) + 82
23  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f237bc5 lldb_private::BreakpointLocation::ShouldStop(lldb_private::StoppointCallbackContext*) + 115
24  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f238816 lldb_private::BreakpointLocationCollection::ShouldStop(lldb_private::StoppointCallbackContext*) + 76
25  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f240a74 lldb_private::BreakpointSite::ShouldStop(lldb_private::StoppointCallbackContext*) + 48
26  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f4739e4 lldb_private::StopInfoBreakpoint::ShouldStopSynchronous(lldb_private::Event*) + 232
27  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f487a1c lldb_private::Thread::ShouldStop(lldb_private::Event*) + 650
28  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f48d285 lldb_private::ThreadList::ShouldStop(lldb_private::Event*) + 483
29  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f46286d lldb_private::Process::ShouldBroadcastEvent(lldb_private::Event*) + 379
30  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f46065e lldb_private::Process::HandlePrivateEvent(std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 356
31  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f46305b lldb_private::Process::RunPrivateStateThread() + 511
32  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010f462a61 lldb_private::Process::PrivateStateThread(void*) + 9
33  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cedc268 _pthread_body + 131
34  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cedc1e5 _pthread_start + 176
35  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ceda41d thread_start + 13
```

Comment: The code signature becomes tainted obviously; either don't code sign it (for your debug) or set the breakpoint elsewhere.

Comment: There is a very similar question here with answers that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135359/xcode-sometimes-crashes-when-i-try-to-debug-in-iphone-simulator-after-i-upgrade